# Changes in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I build app Calculator reduction.

How I use changes with UITextField.

This my code

ViewController.h

```
double p;
double r;
UITextField * priceproduct;
UITextField * percent;
UILabel * result;
UIButton * solve;
```

In priceproduct you write the price of product and in percent you write percent discount of the product.

When you click on button solve it's wirte in label result the price after percent discount of the product.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is defined in the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: The question is pretty unclear but I don't think it is about delegate methods. The OP states the values are already in the two text fields and then the button is tapped. The question seems to be about how to calculate the result and update the label.